# Firebase Angular 2 - Cannot read property 'auth' of null when logout

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I get `Cannot read property 'auth' of null`  when trying to use logout() function of angularfire2.

**firebase.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

  constructor(public af: AngularFire) { }

  fbLogin() {
    return this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    });
  }

  mailLogin(data) {
    console.log(data.email);
    return this.af.auth.login({
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password
    }, {
      provider: AuthProviders.Password,
      method: AuthMethods.Password
    });
  }

  **signOut() {
    return this.af.auth.logout();
  }**

  getInfo() {
    let name: string;
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => auth.auth.displayName === null ? name = auth.auth.email : name = auth.auth.displayName);
    return name;
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../services/firebase.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatroom',
  templateUrl: './chatroom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chatroom.component.css']
})
export class ChatroomComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string = '';
  chats: Chat[];

  constructor(public firebaseService: FirebaseService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = this.firebaseService.getInfo();
  }

  **logout() {
    this.firebaseService.signOut();
  }**
```

**html of app.component.ts**

```
<button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
```

Dependency injection works, since I can successfully log in and retrieve the displayname or email of the current auth